# Forcing the browser to open a download dialog box when a user clicks a document in a document library App

Tags: 2013, document-library, file-upload, app

Currently I have set the following for my document library App:

- On the library advance setting: "Open in the client application"
- On the web application setting: "Strict" for Browser File Handling

If I delete the browser cache and I access the document, then I will be prompted with the download dialog (what I want). But if I re-click on the same document I will be redirected to:

> The webpage cannot be displayed

And the **ms-powerpoint:ofv|u|** (in case of opening a PowerPoint document) will be added to the beginning of the redirected URL.

Could this be a caching problem?

Answer (score 1):

Situation (two clients and SharePoint Server 2013) Client 1:

```
Win7 x64.
Office 2010.
Lync 2010.
Visio 2010.
```

Client 2:

```
Same as Client 1 but added SharePoint Desinger 2013.
```

Problem:

Client 2 not able to open any Visio file by directly clicking a link to open file fron SPS2013. Dont know about Word, Excel and Adobe Reader becouse we use the Web-Apps and that works fine.

Client 1 no problems.

Work around for Client 2:

Right click the link of the Visio file and select either "Open", "Open in new Tab" or "Open in new windows", and a popup will show to either "Open", "Save" or "Save As".

Answer (score 0):

it seems on my machine i  have office 2010 and visio 2013. so i disable the SharePoint support inside the visio and now things is working just fine till now.